# Remove element of a list meeting a logical condition in Python

Tags: python, list, grep

I have filenames listed from arcpy (arcmap) as follows in 'inner'.

```
inner = [u'aet1941jan.asc', u'aet2004jun.asc', u'aet1981nov.asc', u'aet1985feb.asc', u'aet1974sep.asc', u'aet1900sep.asc', u'aet1994apr.asc', u'aet1970nov.asc']
```

I am looking for a way to extract only the rasters that are post-1990.  How can I build a logical expression that remove all elements all the old rasters from the list?

Such that the ouput would be a list:

```
out = [u'aet2004jun.asc', u'aet1994apr.asc']
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A list comprehension is easiest:

```
out = [v for v in inputlist if int(v[3:7]) >= 1990]
```

Note that you cannot name a variable `in`; I used `inputlist` instead.

The above assumes characters 3 through to 6 are always the year in your values.

Comment: you could do it safer by `int(re.sub('[^0-9]','',v) or 0) >= 1990`